# Check both buttons BackgroundResources are same for button

Tags: android, eclipse

I have set the background for button1 and button2 using setBackgroundResource . How to check both buttons BackgroundResources are same in code.

Comment: in code I want to check

Comment: you cannot get the resource id from the button or any other view.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to get the resource id of the backgroundresource you Could try setting tags for the views and compare it using gettag method as.

```
button1.setTag(getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.drawable.your_drawable_name));
button2.setTag(getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.drawable.your_drawable_name));
```

and compare them as:

```
if(button1.gettag==button2.gettag)
       {
        //enter code heredo the thing here }
```